# warning: ISO C90 forbids mixing declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]

Tags: c, c89

I have this c file

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int x,i,sum;
  sum = 0;
  FILE *fin;
  fin = fopen("testdata1", "r");


    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++ ){
      fscanf(fin, "%d", &x);
      sum += x;
    }

    printf("Sum = %d", sum);
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;


}
```

I compiled it via `gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall app.c -o app`

While compiling, I kept getting this **warning error**

> warning: ISO C90 forbids mixing declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
>     FILE *fin;
>           ^
>   1 warning generated.

Any hints on how do I stop that ?

Comment: Compile with `-std=c11`

Comment: I compiled it via `gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall app.c -o app`

Comment: change `-ansi` to `-std=c11`

Comment: I don't think we allow to do that. It's one of the requirement, and plus, I use to not get that error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because in C89/C90, you have to first declare (eventually initialize)
your variables, then put your code. Here is the highlighted problem:

```
int x,i,sum;
sum = 0; // This is code!
FILE *fin;
```

First solution is to initialize `sum` in the declaration:

```
int x,i,sum = 0;
```

Second solution is to initialize `sum` in the beginning of the code:

```
int x,i,sum;
FILE *fin;

sum = 0;
fin = fopen("testdata1", "r");
```

Third solution is to compile using another standard. With gcc/mingw, this is
achieved by passing the command-line option `-std=<your standard>`, for
example, `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` (and remove `-ansi`).